# On POST request, execute a script

Tags: python

I have a simple endpoint for post requests.

Once a user create a post request like below, I'd like to execute a python script(say test.py).

```
[
    {
        "sign": "53535",
    },
    {
        "sign": "42122",
    }
]
```

What's the best way to execute a script on its own when post request comes in? Then when the new post request comes in like 12323 shown below, I'd like to run a python script again on its own.

```
response = requests.get('url')

[
    {
        "sign": "53535",
    },
    {
        "sign": "42122",
    },
    {
        "sign": "12323",
    },
]
```

Comment: what framework are you using?

Comment: @YangK, I'm using Django

Comment: Do you need to save state between requests/session?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly hacky solution:

1. Define some custom [Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/middleware/) which triggers the script using subprocess from the stdlib.
2. Use [decorator_from_middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.decorators.decorator_from_middleware) to create a decorator to allow assignment to individual endpoints
3. assign the decorator to the API endpoint which receives the update.

Every time the endpoint is hit, the middleware will run, and trigger the subprocess which will call your .py file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to inrcept specific requests by applying `Middleware`

For example you can use `Middleware` with `JSON Schema` to intercept specific requests and trigger required scripts.

```
from jsonschema import validate
class CustomMiddleware(object):
    JSON_SCHEMA={
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type" : "object",
            "properties" : {
              "sign" : {
                "type" : "number"
              }
         }  
    }
    def process_request(self, request):
        if 'application/json' in request.META['CONTENT_TYPE'] and  request.method == 'POST':
            data = request.body
            try:
                validate(data, self.JSON_SCHEMA)
                # Schema is valid invoke your hooks
            except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as ve:
                # proceed request further
```

But in case you need to save state between requests, it is better to use `session` to handle this case,

Also do not forget to add this middleware in your `settings.py` like below

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'your.package.CustomMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

By default a middleware catches all requests, therfore you need to filter requests in the `process_request` function.

`JSONSchema` is used to reduce number of `if-else` statements for validating requests, you can define different rules according to your needs just in the declarative way, not in the imperative one. This really makes your code more readable and flexible. You are not ought to use `JSONSchema` this is just a possible way to validate requests.

Comment: Where do you listen to post request at? shouldn't there be an url to listen to? Also, why do you use json_schema? Do you add middleware to the settings?

Comment: @user1702071 You need to add this class as a middleware to your `Django` configuration, I have updated my answer

Comment: Great. What about my first two questions?  Where do you listen to post request at? shouldn't there be an url to listen to? Also, why do you use json_schema?